# Set value of a c:param

Tags: spring, jsp

I have this .jsp code:

```
<c:url value="gridData.do" var="gridDataUrl" scope="page">
    <c:param name="customerId" value="${customerId}" />
</c:url>
```

Depending on a selection in the web page I have to set the value of customerId but I am struggling to set it before gridData.do is called.

Any help?

Comment: You mean you want to change the URL dynamically, in the browser, without sending a request to the server? JSPs are executed at server side. If you want to do that, you'll need JavaScript.

Comment: yes, I mean that, changing the value of the url dynamically. It's ok using javascript but I am struggling with the right code to change the value of the customerId.

Comment: Then remove the irrelevant JSP code, and post the relevant JavaScript code you tried to achieve that.

Comment: You are right Nizet. This is c:url is executed in the server, and so the gridDataUrl is created there. What I did in the end is using this: var useUrl = ${gridDataUrl}+'?customerId='selectedCustomerId';

Answer (score -3):

Try below...

```
<c:url value= "gridData.do" var="gridDataUrl" scope="page">
  <c:param name="customerId" value="${param.customerId}" />
</c:url>
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: What can this fix? I don't even have a 'param' object in the server.